# Other component styles are getting applied to the component which I have not imported

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hello I am working on simple crud application in react js 18.0.0. My problem is I have my own styles for one component say eg..Home. But the styles which I have used for other components is also getting applied to Home component even though I did not imported it. Can anyone explain why? 
I have attached an image for your reference.
[image]
In the above image I was in home component. But if you see the styles the container class in forgetPassword.css and login.css is also getting applied in home component. but In home component I did not imported those two css files(forgetPassword.css and login.css)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example code

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is because by default react does not support css or styles.

you can either use css modules(https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Or

Use styled components.

I suggest you to try the css modules as that will be beginner friendly and easy.

You need to move your css to seperate file and name it `[filename].module.css`

In your case `Home.module.css`

Then in your `Home.js` component import it like `import styles from './Home.module.css'`

Then in your component use it like

`<div className={styles.container} > ... </div>`

I also recommend you not to modify the original bootstrap classes, instead create your custom class and add the overrides there.

eg:

```
<div className={`${styles.container} ${styles.home-container}`} > ... </div>
```